# Take user input and then do execvp

Tags: c, unix, strtok

So I have the following C code which asks the user to give a command (valid in unix), and then I have to take the string and split it in an array in order to execute the command that the user gave with execvp(). It compiles but the execvp doesn't seem to work. Is something wrong in the way I split the user's input in an array? PS: Some of the includes aren't neccessary but it's not the final program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <signal.h>

main() {

  char str[64];
  int i =0;
  char *p = strtok(str," ");

  printf("Please give me a Unix command! :\n");
  gets(str);
  char  *array[sizeof(str)];
  while (p!=NULL) {
    array[i++] = p;
    p = strtok (NULL, " ");
  }

execvp(str ,array);
perror("execvp");
}
```

The output I get when I run this is:

```
Please give me a Unix command! :
ls -l
execvp: No such file or directory
```

Comment: [DO NOT use `gets()`, it is dangerous](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1694036/2173917). use [`fgets()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets) instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling `strtok(str, " ")` before `str` has any information.

Simply call it after you get input:

```
main() {
  char str[64];
  char *array[sizeof(str)];
  char *p = NULL;
  int i = 0;

  printf("Please give me a Unix command! :\n");
  fgets(str, sizeof(str), stdin);  // Use fgets instead of gets.

  p = strtok(str," ");

  while (p != NULL) {
    array[i++] = p;
    p = strtok(NULL, " ");
  }

  execvp(str, array);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The first problem as I see here is with

```
char *p = strtok(str," ");
```

as you're trying to read indeterminate values. `str` is not initialized, there's no guarantee that there is a null-terminator present there which makes this a *string*. So, you're essentially invoking [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

That said,

- [`gets()`, it is dangerous as it lead to buffer overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1694036/2173917). use [`fgets()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets) instead.
- for an array variable, `sizeof(str)` does not give you the size of the *content*, it returns you the size of the whole array. You might want to use `strlen()` to get the length of the *string*, but remember, `strlen()` does not count the null-terminator.